# accessing a variable from inside method to outside method

Tags: android

In android I am working on how to use the variable inside the method. when I used to return a variable it shows the value as 0. I have declared The variable as global.  How can we access the variable to outside method from inside method. Here I called *executeForm(String UID)*

```
public class PaymentMethods extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{
                    private PaymentsClient mPaymentsClient;
                    private  final static int LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 899;
                    float walletbal;
                 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.paymentmethods);


>  executeForm(mAuth.getUid());

// here method is calling
               System.out.println("walletbalance"+walletbal);
        }
    public float executeForm(String UID){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/balance/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
            Retrofit retrofit =  builder.build();
            APIService apiservice=retrofit.create(APIService.class);
            Call<PostData> call=apiservice.bal(UID);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<PostData>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<PostData> call, Response<PostData> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        response.body();
                        String dp = response.body().getToken();
                        Log.d(TAG,dp);
                        //balance.setText(dp);
                    walletbal = Float.parseFloat(dp);

                        System.out.println("wall"+walletbal);



                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    System.out.println("deya"+walletbal);


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<PostData> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG,t.toString());

                }
            });
            System.out.print("dd"+walletbal);
            return walletbal;// here I am getting walletbal as 0
        }





    }
```

Comment: This will not gonna work cause `walletbal` is modifying inside an asynchronous call.   Try to do further task inside `onResponse()` beside returning it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`walletbal` value always 0 because the method code is executed line by line and your actual value you getting from `onResponse()` which getting after getting response. so you need change you method like below :

1) create one interface like below :

```
public interface GetWalletbalValue {
    void getValue(float walletbal);
    void onError(String errorMessage);
}
```

2) change your method like below :

```
public void executeForm(String UID,GetWalletbalValue getWalletbalValue){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/balance/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
        Retrofit retrofit =  builder.build();
        APIService apiservice=retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<PostData> call=apiservice.bal(UID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PostData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostData> call, Response<PostData> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    response.body();
                    String dp = response.body().getToken();
                    Log.d(TAG,dp);
                    //balance.setText(dp);
                    walletbal = Float.parseFloat(dp);

                    System.out.println("wall"+walletbal);
                    getWalletbalValue.getValue(walletbal);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Failure message goes here
                }
                System.out.println("deya"+walletbal);   
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostData> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG,t.toString());
                getWalletbalValue.onError(t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

3) and call this method like below from your activity:

```
executeForm(mAuth.getUid(), new GetWalletbalValue() {
            @Override
            public void getValue(float walletbal) {
                System.out.println("wall"+walletbal); //here you will get value
            }

           @Override
           public void onError(String errorMessage) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
```

Comment: i am not getting value

Comment: executeForm(mAuth.getUid(), new GetWalletbalValue() {
            @Override
            public void getValue(float walletbal) {
                System.out.println("wall"+walletbal); //here you will get value
            }
        }); This method is not calling

Comment: Hey I got the answer. But I have a doubt Why we need to write the interface

Comment: But sometime I am getting java.net.sockettimeoutexception: timeout retrofit

Comment: because we should to wait till the response come from web service. So, we need to implement interface in this. when sometime you got error of time out, because the response from your server is not getting quickly. it taking more time than ideal request time. or may be your internet connection is slow then time out error can occured.

Comment: yaa. I got sometimes socket timeout error then again I run the programme. Thank you